# Where is defined the default material-ui spacing?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, themes

I've realized the default spacing for material-ui themes is 8px. `theme.spacing(1)` is equal to 8px. `theme.spacing(2)` is equal to 16px, and so on. I know spacing works in a overriding way, so it's possible to write `<Box m={4} />` or `theme = {spacing: 4}`. However, I'm interested in knowing where it was defined that the spacing is 8px by default.

Note:
The default theme here [DefaultTheme](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/#default-theme) doesn't have a defined spacing, I couldn't find it in the material-ui repo either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Default theme](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createMuiTheme.js) defines spacing as result of `createSpacing` function:

```js
function createMuiTheme(options = {}) {
  const {
    // ...
    spacing: spacingInput,
    // ...
  } = options;

  // ...
  const spacing = createSpacing(spacingInput);
  // ...
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createSpacing.js) is definition of `createSpacing` function.

```js
export default function createSpacing(spacingInput = 8) {
  // ...
  const spacing = (...args) => {
  // ...
  }
  // ...
  return spacing
}
```

Comment: For 2022 update,

createTheme
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-system/src/createTheme/createTheme.js

createSpacing
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-system/src/createTheme/createSpacing.ts

Answer (score 0):

> Where it's defined?

Somewhere in the code but I'm not sure if pointing out where in the code makes any difference, maybe you want to know...

> Why it's 8px?

It's a standard of [Material's Design](https://material.io/design/layout/understanding-layout.html#)

> How to change it?

You can see it [in the docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/spacing/).

Comment: It was really interesting to know the material design specification, thanks